# Json_normalise from nested API to DF throwing type error

Tags: python, json, pandas, json-normalize

I'm trying to consume an api that has the following structure and load it into a pandas DF with one row per item ID e.g. 2, 6 and columns for the high, hightime, low and lowtime for each entry.

```
{
"data": {
    "2": {
        "high": 142,
        "highTime": 1617214328,
        "low": 140,
        "lowTime": 1617214323
    },
    "6": {
        "high": 182198,
        "highTime": 1617214063,
        "low": 182198,
        "lowTime": 1617214137
```

So far I've been using json_normalise on the json response which loads one row with multiple nested columns for each entry:

```
data.2.high | data.2.highTime | data.2.low | data.2.lowTime etc
```

as I result, I tried adding the record_path for 'data' thinking that would address the fact that it's a nested list but doing so throws

```
 raise TypeError(
257                     f"{js} has non list value {result} for path {spec}. "
258                     "Must be list or null."
```

I think that's because my res['data'] type is a dict, not a list in it's own right but I'm slightly confused how to go about solving that or if that's even right.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does the code `df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(json_data['data']).T` works?

Comment: Yes! That works perfectly. Can you explain to me why this was the correct way instead of json_normalise or otherwise? Thanks :)

Comment: I explained it below, let me know if it is clear =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Just use

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(json_data['data']).T.reset_index()
```

### Explanation

In your scenario, pandas `from_records` works better than `json_normalise`. This the case because your response is structured in a way that the ids are the keys and not the values.

For instance, for this response example where there is a key `id` and its correspondent value

```
json_data={
"data": [{
        "id":2,
        "high": 142,
        "highTime": 1617214328,
        "low": 140,
        "lowTime": 1617214323
    },{
        "id":6,
        "high": 182198,
        "highTime": 1617214063,
        "low": 182198,
        "lowTime": 1617214137
    }]}
```

would work fine with `json_normalize`, as follows.

```
pd.json_normalize(json_data['data'])
```

```
id  high    highTime    low     lowTime
2   142     1617214328  140     1617214323
6   182198  1617214063  182198  1617214137
```

However, your JSON response contains ids as keys,

```
json_data={
"data": {
    "2": {
        "high": 142,
        "highTime": 1617214328,
        "low": 140,
        "lowTime": 1617214323
    },
    "6": {
        "high": 182198,
        "highTime": 1617214063,
        "low": 182198,
        "lowTime": 1617214137
    }}}
```

and so `from_records` works better.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(json_data['data']).T.reset_index()
```

```
index   high    highTime    low     lowTime
2       142     1617214328  140     1617214323
6       182198  1617214063  182198  1617214137
```

Also, things were not working because you probably were passing the full json response `json_data` instead of selecting by the data key `json_data['data']`.